# Merge tags x509 and x.509

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

As per [How to suggest tags to be merged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92043/how-to-suggest-tags-to-be-merged) I suggest that the tags [x509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509) and [x.509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x.509) should be merged, as they mean the same thing.

From Tag-Wiki:

- [x509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509): In cryptography, X.509 is a standard for a public key infrastructure (PKI) for single sign-on (SSO) and Privilege Management Infrastructure (PMI). X.509 specifies, amongst other things, standard formats for public key certificates, certificate revocation lists, attribute certificates, and a certification path validation algorithm. ...
- [x.509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x.509): X.509 is an standard for a public key infrastructure used for authentication and access control. X.509 specifies standard formats for certificates, revocation lists, attribute certificates, and path validation. In cryptography, X.509 is an ITU-T standard for a public key infrastructure (PKI) for single sign-on (SSO) and Privilege Management Infrastructure (PMI). X.509 specifies, amongst other things, standard formats for public key certificates, certificate revocation lists, attribute certificates, and a certification path validation algorithm. ...

Comment: Which should be the master tag?

Comment: @ChrisF X.509 is the official name. x509 is used by 505 questions, x.509 by 168.  What is more important, number of questions or "correctness"? I would use x.509 as master, but I think it's a close call.

Comment: Also make sure to merge the tag wikis before merging the tags; one wiki is more detailed than the other.  You wouldn't want to lose that (if it in fact good information) if that tag isn't chosen.

Comment: I have copied the explanation from x.509 to x509